# How to register aliased class as global class

Tags: php

#### /Core/Api.php

```
<?php namespace Core;

class Api
{
//
}
```

#### start.php

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

#### index.php

```
<?php

include 'start.php';

use Core\Api as Api;

new Api // it's work
```

---

#### start.php

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php'

use Core\Api as Api;
```

#### index.php

```
<?php

include 'start.php';

new Api; // Fatal error: Class 'Api' not found
```

There are many tool class will be used in many places, how to alias it as once in some file and let other file can use the aliased name directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` works inside current namespace (for a whole file in most cases) only.

You could create empty class to inheritance target class.

```
<?php

class Api extends \Core\Api
    {}
```